# PHP - Session variables with prepared statements and parameterized queries

Tags: php, sql, session, prepared-statement, parameterized-query

I tried to write a registration form. On submition it suppose to:

- Get the data from the inputs to the sql database - as a row in the table.
- Add the users email address as a session variable.
- Redirects them to a second page.

It all happens, but it adds **two identical rows** instead of one.

I'll appreciate any answer you can give me that will explain why my script adds the same row twice into the database.

PHP:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

if($_POST) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $error = "";
    $link = mysqli_connect("xx", "xx", "xx", "xx");
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        die("the connection was failed");
    }
    if ($email || $password || $name) {
        $stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO `Family` (email, password, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $email, $password, $name);
        $stmt->execute();
        if($stmt->execute()) { 
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            header("Location: session.php");
            $stmt->close();
        } else {
            echo "it failed";
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Registration Form</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <p>Email:</p>
        <input type="email" name="email">
        <p>Password:</p>
        <input type="password" name="password">
        <p>Name:</p>
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <br><br><br>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you have two `$stmt->execute()`.

Comment: Use one of these $stmt->execute(); if($stmt->execute()) I think use in if remove other one will solve the problem.